# Access iterable in sibling tag

Tags: html, vue.js

As stated i want to access an iterable from a sibling tag. Unfortunatly its in a table so i cant just do it by wrapping the stuff with a diff and push the iteration one lvl outside. Also the items are tablerows so i cant make the sibling to a child. I guess this is easier with an example(thats what i want to do):

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="element in elements">
    ...
   </tr>
   <tr v-for="hit in element.hits">
     ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

Obviously this doesnt work since once i close the first tr i drop out of scope. Is there any work around that?
Regardiest regards,
Sean

Comment: v-for can be used on <template> that wraps <tr>

Comment: Much appreciated!!!!!! Unfortunatly i cant mark it as an answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-for` can be used on `<template>` that wraps `<tr>`, in this case it isn't rendered itself:

```
<template v-for="element in elements">
  <tr>
    ...
   </tr>
   <tr v-for="hit in element.hits">
     ...
   </tr>
</template>
```